# Plotting cartesian coordinate data point in spherical coordinate

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

```
 I have field value in cartisian coordinate i.e. {x,y,z,Ex,Ey,Ez}=
```

{{-6.1935, 0.1505, -6.4695, 41186.7, 68876.6, -8859.19}, {-5.5125, 
  0.1505, -6.4695, 3914.28, 149235, 15848.8}, {-4.8315, 
  0.1505, -6.4695, -12290.5, 16073.4, 3135.46}, {-4.1505, 
  0.1505, -6.4695, -14043.7, -95001.8, -16983}, {-3.4695, 
  0.1505, -6.4695, 36911.1, 57960.9, 6953.94}, {-2.7885, 
  0.1505, -6.4695, -20771.9, 41121.2, -13638.4}, {-2.1075, 
  0.1505, -6.4695, -18273.4, 27652.3, -21044.5}}
   I want to plot it in a spherical coordinate. Plese suggest it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And I assume that's a vector field?

Comment: @user6014, yes you can assume.

Comment: *What* exactly do you want to plot? *How* do you want the `{Ex,Ey,Ez}` portions of the set to be represented?

Comment: @CA, yes If want to plot  it in term of spherical  (r,theta,pi, E), you can take resultent of Ex,Ey and Ez.

Comment: Yes, definitely, but *what* do you want to do with them? You have consistently not answered this point. Take the resultant and do what? Color them? Make an arrow? If so, what does each argument influence? Is it a direction in a coordinate system with respect to the spherical coordinates? *Please, be specific.*

Comment: @CA, just color them to see the each argument influence.

Comment: @GopalVerma okay, we can easily do that! Great idea. I’ll update the answer in a couple hours or less :) I’ll show you a nice method to implement any sort of representation of your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I welcome you to clarify your question a bit further as to what exactly you want to do with the data, and I will update this answer a bit further. For now, I invite you to see the following method for converting your coordinates to spherical ones:

Given a set of data

```
set = {{-6.1935, 0.1505, -6.4695, 0, 1, .01}, {-5.5125, 0.1505, -6.4695, 0, 
  1.1, .04}, {x, y, z, Ex, Ey, Ez}};
```

We can convert merely the first three entries of each item in the list using [`ToSphericalCoordinates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToSphericalCoordinates.html) and rejoin the list up

```
{ToSphericalCoordinates@set[[All, ;; 3]], set[[All, -3 ;;]]} // 
  Transpose // Join @@@ # &

(*{{8.95748, 2.37784, 3.1173, 0, 1, 0.01}, {8.50087, 2.43571, 3.1143, 0,
   1.1, 0.04}, {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], 
  ArcTan[x, y], Ex, Ey, Ez}}*)
```

From here, we can use similar techniques using [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) in order to plot with the coordinates being styled by the E-values.

As an update, using your new set of data, you can play with this a bit more:

```
set = {{-6.1935, 0.1505, -6.4695, 41186.7, 
    68876.6, -8859.19}, {-5.5125, 0.1505, -6.4695, 3914.28, 149235, 
    15848.8}, {-4.8315, 0.1505, -6.4695, -12290.5, 16073.4, 
    3135.46}, {-4.1505, 
    0.1505, -6.4695, -14043.7, -95001.8, -16983}, {-3.4695, 
    0.1505, -6.4695, 36911.1, 57960.9, 6953.94}, {-2.7885, 
    0.1505, -6.4695, -20771.9, 41121.2, -13638.4}, {-2.1075, 
    0.1505, -6.4695, -18273.4, 27652.3, -21044.5}};
colorSystem = RGBColor;
setsplit = {set[[All, ;; 3]], 
     colorSystem[#/Norm[#]] & /@ set[[All, -3 ;;]]} // Transpose // 
   Join@# &;
Graphics3D[{Directive[#[[2]]], Point[#[[1]]]} & /@ setsplit, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image: SE Image For Spherical Coordinates]

While the color changes, your coordinates don't seem to change much in terms of on a spherical surface. This should work pretty readily with your whole set of data as long as you name it `set`. You can change the color system used by changing the value of `colorSystem`.

Comment: Thanks, I have uploaded more data points. Still, I am not able to plot in spherical coordinate

Comment: This still does not explain what you want to do. What do you want to do exactly? Be precise & update your question, please? You can easily plot in spherical coordinates with this method, even easier is to use your unmodified data.

Comment: @GopalVerma see update :)